# How to create a JavaScript loop that adds DOM properties to attributes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I have a table with cells that are not `contentEditable`. However, using a JavaScript loop or function, I would like to make them so.

I understand that it is very simple to do this manually for each cell, and this would probably be easier for a table with only a few cells, but I would like to quicken this process with a loop/function for the table could become much larger, and the time spent manually setting each cell to be contentEditable would be tedious.

Below is a quick example that displays a table calculator, un-editable at present. But using a loop or function, I'd like to make every cell in the right column set to `.contentEditable = true` in the DOM. I imagine that the parameters would look something like `(var i = 0; l != rows.length; i < l; i+2)`, but I'm struggling with what the statements following the argument would have to be for the loop/function to work. Any help would be much appreciated!

```js
function myFunction() {
  var jack2 = document.getElementById("jack").innerText;
  var john2 = document.getElementById("john").innerText;
  var joe2 = document.getElementById("joe").innerText;

  var total2 = (parseInt(jack2) || 0) + (parseInt(john2) || 0) + (parseInt(joe2) || 0);

  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total2;
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table,
tr,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Weight Calculator</caption>
  <tr class="cell">
    <th>Person</th>
    <th>Weight (kg)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cell">
    <td>Jack</td>
    <td id="jack" oninput="myFunction()">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cell">
    <td>John</td>
    <td id="john" oninput="myFunction()">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cell">
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td id="joe" oninput="myFunction()">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cell">
    <td>Total</td>
    <td id="total"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all cell in the tabel that have a left neigbour (the header is not effected because there are th and not td). Add to each of these cells your attribute.
**Edited:** For getting the totalsum add an eventlistener on each td that calls the calc-function if the content changes.

```js
function myFunction() {
    let weightCells = document.querySelectorAll("table tr:not(:last-child) td ~ td");
    weightCells.forEach(td => {
        td.setAttribute('contentEditable', true);
        td.addEventListener ("change", calcSum());
    });
}

function calcSum() {
    let sum=0;
    let weightCells = document.querySelectorAll("table tr td ~ td");
    let count = weightCells.length-1;
    for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
        sum +=  parseInt(weightCells[i].innerHTML) || 0;
    }
  weightCells[count].innerHTML = sum;
}

myFunction();
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table,
tr,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Weight Calculator</caption>
  <tr class="cell">
    <th>Person</th>
    <th>Weight (kg)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cell">
    <td>Jack</td>
    <td id="jack" oninput="myFunction()">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cell">
    <td>John</td>
    <td id="john" oninput="myFunction()">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cell">
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td id="joe" oninput="myFunction()">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cell">
    <td>Total</td>
    <td id="total"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the whole table, then use querySelectorAll to get all rows then for each rows change the contenteditable for the second td like this

[codepen](https://codepen.io/gui3/pen/BajXgzJ)

```js
let table = document.getElementById('table')
let rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr')

rows.forEach(row => {
  let tds = row.querySelectorAll('td') 
  // all the cells of the row
  if (tds.length > 0) { // if it is not the header
    tds[1].contentEditable = true 
    // change the contenteditable
  }
})
```

(you need to add an id to your table in case you have more than one table)

```html
<table id="table">
...
</table>
```

Comment: This is great, but it also makes the final cell editable. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Yes you can fix that look at my answer. The selector could be a little bit extended.